# After screen is off in 5 minutes wifi is disabled.

Tags: android

I have found good tutorial to for Handling Screen OFF and Screen ON Intents:
http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/

but i want that after screen is off in 5 minutes wifi is disabled.

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wm.setWifiEnabled(true);
```

My only problem is how to achive 5 minutes interval? Do I need some timepickers or what is best practice for this when you are dealing with calculating and counting time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Timer` for this:

```
private final int delayTime = 5 * 1000 * 60;
private Handler myHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable closeScreen = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //Make screen Off here
    }
};
```

and start the `Timer` like this:

```
myHandler.postDelayed(closeControls, delayTime);
```